# Finding the Big $\Theta$ of inverse factorial

Tags: asymptotics, inverse, factorial

I'm having trouble finding $g(n)$ such that $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ where $f(n)$ is the inverse factorial ( $f(1)=1$ , $f(2)=f(3)=f(4)=f(5)=2$ , $f(6)....f(23)=3$, $f(24)=4$ and so on.) A hint on how to solve this will much be appreciated!

Comment: I think you should use $\Theta$ (`$\Theta$`) instead of $\theta$?

Comment: [Somewhat dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36729/asymptotic-behavior-of-gamma-1x)? (not really)